# Tivoli command line to search objects

Tags: tivoli-work-scheduler

Is there a CLI command to find Tivoli objects that matches a search pattern?
**For example, I need to search if any object with name containing "DUMMY" is present? If so, what is the type of the object (is it a Job Stream, or a Tivoli Job or a Calendar or an Event or a Resource)**

I came across a concept that Tivoli stores all its object defiNitions in a database like repository, and we can execute SQL like SELECT queries as to find the object definition, but I am not sure how to do that using a  CLI command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**composer** command line allows to filter using wildcards (@ and ?), but you have to run the command once for each object type